# Parsing list of string to new json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Using .Net Nore C# MVC

I have the following code:

My data:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetData(string id)
{
    return  _context.TableData
            .Where(r => r.ID == id)
            .Select (r => r.Name).ToList();
}
```

My MVC controller:

```
public IActionResult GetDDL(string id)
{
    var result = _repo.GetData(id);

    //Above gives me
    //[0] = "United States"
    //[1] = "United Kingdom"

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);      
    //Above json convert gives me ["United States","United Kingdom"]

    return Json(json);
}
```

Above code does return me Json but I wanted to know how can I create new JSON such that it return me as below:

```
[{"Text":"United States","Text":"United Kingdom"}]
```

Basically, I want to bind this back to my dropdown which expects the "Text" property with the JSON array.

Comment: try : `var textResult = result.Select(x=> new { Text = x});`

Comment: Thanks that works fine. Would it be possible to somehow refine my Linq code in my repo to return the above instead of creating a new result.

Comment: Don't add `ToList()` after the `Select`, it materializes the `IEnumerable<T>`. Also, since you specifically expect an `IEnumerable<string>` from the method, you shouldn't convert it to a `List<string>`.

Comment: @kaka1234 in the case you need to add this line  in the method.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad which line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. In the controller

```
public IActionResult GetDDL(string id)
{
    var result = _repo.GetData(id);
    var withProp = result.Select(x => new { Text = x });
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(withProp);      
    return Json(json);

    //Or shorter:
    var result = _repo.GetData(id).Select(x => new { Text = x });
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);      
    return Json(json); 
}
```

### 2. In the repository

You cannot return an anonymous type so you should create a class that'll hold the data and use that to return from the repository:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Data> GetData(string id)
{
    return  _context.TableData
                    .Where(r => r.ID == id)
                    .Select (r => new Data { Text = r.Name });
}
```

Usage in the controller remains unchanged then:

```
public IActionResult GetDDL(string id)
{
    var result = _repo.GetData(id);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);      
    return Json(json);
}
```

Comment: Is this line correct: .Select (r => new Data { Text = r.Name });  as intellisense cannot find r.Name and errors out.

Comment: @kaka1234 the method body was wrong, I corrected it from `IEnumerable <string>` to `IEnumerable <Data>`.